# Join three tables, same column name in all three

Tags: mysql, join

**Update: I may have found a possible issue, running the code directly in phpmyadmin told me that there was a collation mismatch, one being utf8_unicode, and the other being utf8_general. currently in the process of making them the same, and going to try again**

#### table1

- companyid
- companytype
- ordernumber

#### table2

- newcontract
- companyid
- ordernumber
- datesigned

#### table3

- companyid
- companyname

So, I need a mysql SELECT code that will use two JOIN statements, connecting companyid across all three. Here is what I have using just one JOIN statement, but any time I try to add a second, it errors.

```
SELECT 
    table2.newcontract,
    table2.ordernumber,
    table2.companyid,
    table2.datesigned,
    table3.companyname 
FROM 
    table2
JOIN 
    table3 ON table2.companyid=table3.companyid 
WHERE 
    table2.companyid LIKE '%".$companyid."%' 
    AND table2.ordernumber LIKE '%".$ordernumber."%' 
    AND table2.datesigned > '".$date."' 
ORDER BY 
    table2.datesigned desc
```

I've tried to add:

```
JOIN table1 ON table2.companyid=table1.companyid
```

But no luck.

Comment: Is the data type of `companyid` the same across all three tables?

Comment: Also, it looks like you have a typo in your proposed additional join: `JOIN table1 on table12...` shouldn't it be `table2` rather than `table12`?

Comment: Yes, should be table2, but that wasnt the error, that was quickly typing up here. The error is no results found. companyid is varchar 255 across all three.

Comment: Can you show your code with that line you're trying to add in it?

Comment: Update: I may have found a possible issue, running the code directly in phpmyadmin told me that there was a collation mismatch, one being utf8_unicode, and the other being utf8_general. currently in the process of making them the same, and going to try again.

Answer (score -1):

Try something like the following

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.*, t3.* FROM table1 AS t1
JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
JOIN table3 AS t3 ON t2.id = t3.id
WHERE t1.id = 'something'
```

Comment: This doesn't really do anything for OP. Aliases are not mandatory, and you've really done nothing to explain how your proposed query is helpful.

Comment: Aliases are not mandatory but they help to simplify things. Without doing the work for the OP I've provided a simplified suggestion to help him join 3 tables on a similarly named field in each so he/she may be able to get it working.